# getting invalid procedure call or argument in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have the below code..I am getting an invalid call or procedure at this statement  txsOutput.Writeline txsInput1.ReadAll ..The combination file is ust a text file which has some entries in this format

name test.css.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the script.

```
Dim strInputPath1
Dim txsInput1,txsOutput
Dim FSO

Dim Filename


Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strOutputPath = "C:\txt3.txt"
Set txsOutput = FSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputPath)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True

Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\combination.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  tokens = Split(Trim(re.Replace(f.ReadLine, " ")))
  extension = Split(tokens(0),".")
  strInputPath1 =  "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\data\p\" & tokens(1) & "\" & extension(1) & "\" & tokens(0) 

Loop
f.Close

WScript.Echo strInputPath1

Set txsInput1 = FSO.OpenTextFile(strInputPath1, 1)
txsOutput.Writeline txsInput1.ReadAll

txsInput1.Close
txsOutput.Close
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error 5 when calling TextStream.WriteLine is typically caused by trying to write data the TextStream can't encode:

Trying to write "U+1F00 ἀ e1 bc 80 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH PSILI" to a stream opened with/for 'ASCII' encoding:

```
>> Set f = goFS.CreateTextFile(".\tmp.txt")
>> f.WriteLine "AÄ"
>>  --- no news here means: written ---
>> f.WriteLine ChrW(&H1F00)
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
```

To prove this:

```
>> f.close
>> Set f = goFS.CreateTextFile(".\tmp.txt", True, True) ' overwrite, unicode
>> f.WriteLine ChrW(&H1F00)
>>
>> --- no news are good news --
```

As the data source (.ReadAll()) seems to come from the WWW, it's probable that it contains non ASCII/ANSI text. Be warned though, just opening the output file for Unicode (=UTF-16) won't help if the input is UTF-8 slurped by .ReadAll() on a ASCII Textstream.

Comment: I guess u are right..I have one specific css file which is throwing error but other like js and other css are working correctly..not sure what's going on with that file.

Comment: I used the first proposition with only 2 parameters, and it did work sometimes (I get my data from a mssql server database). It seems like it works everytime with the solution you gave. Does it mean that forcing overwrite uses the correct encoding ? (Thanks by the way)

Comment: No, the **second** True (unicode) is the true solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing that particular input file there isn't much more we can tell you. However, you may be able to isolate the source of the error by replacing:

```
txsOutput.Writeline txsInput1.ReadAll
```

with something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Do Until txsInput1.AtEndOfStream
  line = txsInput1.ReadLine
  If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Operation:   Read" & vbNewLine _
      "Error:       " & Err.Number & vbNewLine _
      "Description: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine _
      "Line:        " & txsInput1.Line
    WScript.Echo "Text:        " & line
  End If
  Err.Clear

  txsOutput.WriteLine line
  If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Operation:   Write" & vbNewLine _
      "Error:       " & Err.Number & vbNewLine _
      "Description: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine _
      "Line:        " & txsInput1.Line
    WScript.Echo "Text:        " & line
  End If
  Err.Clear
Loop
On Error Goto 0
```

Inspecting the input file with a hex editor may also be an option.